# install Wx::Perl::SplashFast or any Wx perl modules is driving me insane on mac OS El Capitan 10.11.5

Tags: macos, perl, perl-module, wxwidgets

I have tried again and again to install any of the Perl `Wx` modules including [`Wx::Perl::SplashFast`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Wx::Perl::SplashFast) without any success. I have a program that needs this module and I have successful installed all the required modules expect `Wx` and anything related.

I used `sudo cpan -f Wx::Perl::SplashFast` and I get the error:

```
make: *** [Wx.o] Error 1
  MDOOTSON/Wx-0.9928.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- NOT OK
'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
```

Please note that I have wxpython installed in the system path at
`/usr/local/lib/wxPython-3.0.2.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-3.0-osx_cocoa/wx`
and other programs that require wxpython work fine. It is a challenge to install these Perl modules.

Could anyone help please?

Edit:
Here is the log from failed cpanm Wx:

```
    cpanm (App::cpanminus) 1.7042 on perl 5.018002 built for darwin-2level
Work directory is /Users/STGNU/.cpanm/work/1464453743.57963
You have make /usr/bin/make
You have LWP 6.15
You have /usr/bin/tar: bsdtar 2.8.3 - libarchive 2.8.3
You have /usr/bin/unzip
Searching Wx () on cpanmetadb ...
--> Working on Wx
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/M/MD/MDOOTSON/Wx-0.9928.tar.gz
-> OK
Unpacking Wx-0.9928.tar.gz
Entering Wx-0.9928
Checking configure dependencies from META.json
Checking if you have Alien::wxWidgets 0.25 ... Yes (0.67)
Configuring Wx-0.9928
Running Makefile.PL
Searching configuration for:
wxWidgets (any version) for (any toolkit); compiler compatibility: gcc 3.4; 

Available configurations:
wxWidgets 3.000002 for mac; compiler compatibility: nc 0; options: no debug, unicode, no mslu
Compilation failed in require at Makefile.PL line 21.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Makefile.PL line 21.
-> N/A
-> FAIL Configure failed for Wx-0.9928. See /Users/STGNU/.cpanm/work/1464453743.57963/build.log for details.
```

Comment: Do you have a C compiler installed on your system?  It is probably croaking when trying to invoke a compiler which doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes I have the gcc properly installed.

Comment: Try using cpan interactively.  You can run the get/make/test/install steps one at a time and look to see what happened.  Try running the make step and see what errors you get.  It is likely you are missing a tool or a dependency.  Enter cpan and then type 'h' for help.

Comment: Thanks again. But I tried that too with no luck. I also tried to install wx-0.9928 from source but also with no luck; the build exists with an error.                                                                                                                         ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/FSEvents.framework/Headers/FSEvents.h:497:1: error: expected declaration before '}' token
 };
 ^
make: *** [Wx.o] Error 1

Comment: please see the failed cpanm Wx log above

Comment: Have a look at Makefile.PL line 21 and see what package it needs.

Comment: Line 21 is:  (use Wx::build::MakeMaker::Core;). I tried to install it but this also fails!

Comment: I have wasted a lot of time on this, searched almost everywhere. My conclusion is that OSX is the wrong place to do science. I gave up on this!!

Comment: Have a look at CPAN testers: http://www.cpantesters.org/distro/W/Wx.html  maybe there is a combo of Mac + perl that is known to work.  http://matrix.cpantesters.org/?dist=Wx+0.9928

Comment: Do you have `make` installed?

Comment: Yes, I do have make installed. Also have tried the tested perl versions 5.24.0. 5.19.1, and 5.18.2. All of them fail Wx. I must add that I have Homebrew installed but I cannot see that a problem since many other Perl formulas were installed correctly.